# Refactor multiple StringBuilder.Append statements

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

Today i saw this bad code structure and since then i started to think its really awkward and horrible to look at this method having this code. The code goes like this:

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();       

            #region General
            body.Append("General information:");
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Exception:         ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.GetType().ToString());
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Message:           ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.Message);
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Method:            ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.GetMethodName(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception));
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Class:             ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.GetClassName(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception));
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Assembly:          ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.AssemblyName);
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("App-Domain:        ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.AppDomainName);
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Source-File:       ");
            body.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.GetFileName(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception));
            body.Append('*');
            body.Append("Line/Row:          ");
            body.Append(
                m_ExceptionInfo.GetFileLineNumber(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception).ToString(currentNumberFormatInfoProvider));
```

This we are doing to customize the displayed error message box information in the UI. So for that we are preparing a string having such many information. But to me its feels bad to look at this code and not have any idea how to refactor it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you don't like all the spaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx

Comment: By the way: to make you feel less bad: you use a `StringBuilder`! that's much better then default string concatenation.

Comment: What exactly is bothering you about this code?

Comment: Actually the above is just half of what i have here. The method has such statements like 50 or so. Ya imagine how some stupid dev has written it? Well although no body asked me to fix it, but i hate looking at it. Plus any small change, it kicks me hard to carefully see line by line. tedious task!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder.AppendFormat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) method:

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();    
body.AppendFormat("Exception: {0}, Message: {1}{2}Class: {3}, Assembly: {4}{5}", 
                            m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.GetType(),
                            m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.Message,
                            Environment.NewLine,                              
                            m_ExceptionInfo.GetClassName(...),
                            m_ExceptionInfo.AssemblyName,
                            Environment.NewLine);

body.AppendFormat("App-Domain: {0}, Source-File: {1}{2}",
                            m_ExceptionInfo.AppDomainName,
                            m_ExceptionInfo.GetFileName(...),
                            Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Well i already looked at it, even using that as well increases the lenght of the line AppendFormat() to a lenghty one. From vertial growth it would be reduced to horizontal if used this. Thats all.

Comment: @zenwalker : you can use multiple AppnedFormat() calls

Comment: Use AppendFormat and combine them thematically. 3 lines for a single exception message is IMHO exageration

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a simple collection of string pairs and then iterate through them to build the actual string? eg:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> info = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 info.Add("General information", "*");
 info.Add("Exception", m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.GetType().ToString());
 info.Add("Message",   m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.Message);
 //etc

 StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();  
 foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> stringPair in info)
     body.AppendFormat("{0}:{1, 20}", stringPair.Key, stringPair.Value);
```

Comment: The same number of Append lines we are repeating on Dictionary.Add statements.

Comment: Nope, there's half as many, and you don't need to worry about alignment

Answer (score 0):

Creating seperate methods with meaningful names for each bit of information being added would make this method seem nicer:

```
private void AppendExceptionMessage(StringBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Append("Message:           ");
    builder.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception.Message);
    builder.Append('*');
}

private void AppendMethodInfo(StringBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Append("Method:            ");
    builder.Append(m_ExceptionInfo.GetMethodName(m_ExceptionInfo.Exception));
    builder.Append('*');
}

body.Append("General information:");
body.Append('*');
body.Append('*');
AppendExceptionMessage(body);
AppendMethodInfo(body);
```

Comment: I already thought of that, but the problem is, every time i need to do some changes, this big mess has to be looked detaily. Basically i am looking to reduce the number of Append lines.